# Android cash : UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "pthread_cond_clockwait"

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, crash, build.gradle, unsatisfiedlinkerror

1. I am trying to import native libraries(.so files) into the android studio.
2. I created a jniLibs folder and directory with ABI name and respective .so files in it.
   made changes in build.gradle and tried to load them.
3. Then, the error occurs of **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "pthread_cond_clockwait"**
   can someone give idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That API is [only available on API 30+ devices](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:bionic/libc/include/pthread.h;l=124-125;drc=fa658eb094d915a9640a4d0642adee7667f439e7) (note the `__INTRODUCED_IN(30)`):

```c
int pthread_cond_clockwait(pthread_cond_t* __cond,
                           pthread_mutex_t* __mutex,
                           clockid_t __clock,
                           const struct timespec* __timeout) __INTRODUCED_IN(30);
```

You're probably seeing the problem on an older device.

As per [the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/common-problems#minsdkversion_set_higher_than_device_api_level), it is important to realize that the **NDK API level is your app's minimum supported API level**:

> The API level you build against with the NDK has a very different meaning than compileSdkVersion does for Java. The NDK API level is your app's minimum supported API level. In ndk-build, this is your APP_PLATFORM setting. With CMake, this is -DANDROID_PLATFORM.

So you need to compile the library with the correct NDK API level:

> **Problem**: Your NDK API level is higher than the API supported by your device.
>
> **Solution**: Set your NDK API level (APP_PLATFORM) to the minimum version of Android your app supports.